# Differential Cross Section

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I would like to know what exactly the term [differential cross section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_cross-section) means. It comes from electron scattering experiments which are used to deduce the charge distribution of a nucleus and the cross section is given as a function of the scattering angle. But I don't understand what it means.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia pages on [cross-section (physics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) and [scattering cross-section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_cross-section)?

Comment: Thanks, I did have a read through the wiki page on cross section (physics) and didn't understand it very well, but I have had a look now at the scattering cross-section page and seem to have finally understood it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Differential cross section is defined to be:

$$ \dfrac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} $$

In plain words, this expression gives the probability that a particle passing through an area of $d\sigma$ before scattering can be found within the solid angle $ d\Omega $ after scattering.

This Wikipedia image can give a clear picture
[image: Differential cross section figure]

Comment: This is by far the simplest explanation I've come across.